# PHP's mcrypt_encrypt and openssl command line output different cipher

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, aes

I am new to encryption. I want to encode a string with AES 128bit encryption. I can do this in PHP:

```
$key = 'Hello';
$plain = 'Hello Hello Hello Hello';

$cipher = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plain, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);

echo base64_encode($cipher);
```

This outputs:

```
bzXdTNochlsQwpR9hzSSS6ihG+MYIZIDZZlF85pIXlQ=
```

I tried the same with openssl command line:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -nosalt -in plain.txt -out encrypted.enc -pass pass:Hello
```

And the string saved in encrypted.enc is:

```
5apwiN8MdAuJ9nEW82XMyR0H3VKpI/vWc7xV2iVjCTE=
```

Why is it different?

The reason why I am trying to get the same output with both PHP and command line openssl is because I will have two separate web services communicating together. One service will have PHP available so I can use that but the other one will not be using PHP so I will probably have to use openssl in command line.

Comment: MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 might not be the same as aes-128 probably? Also `-pass pass:Hello` does not look like to set the same password. And I think good encryption does not look always the same even the plain and the password are the same. It is more important if you can decrypt what you have crypted with the other one and vice-versa.

Comment: RIJNDAEL is AES -- the only difference is in block size but 128 makes it the same. While pass:Hello does specify the password Hello for enc, openssl needs to derive a key, while mcrypt uses a key not the password. Finally, good encryption as you say might be different depending on the Initialization Vector but no good algorithm uses a random from inside the algo. Same starting values, same results. He has many problems with the starting values: the plain is padded differently, the key is derived differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up password and key. Add a `-p` to your openssl command line to see the actual key used and observe http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php `string mcrypt_encrypt ( string $cipher , string $key` <= key! Not password.

Edit:

You also have problems with padding. Now making your plain text 48 chars (3*128 bit=3*16 bytes) long:

```
$plain = 'Hello Hello Hello Hellox';
$plain .= $plain;
function hexstr($hexstr) {
  // return pack('H*', $hexstr); also works but it's much harder to understand.
  $return = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hexstr); $i+=2) {
    $return .= chr(hexdec($hexstr[$i] . $hexstr[$i+1]));
  }
  return $return;
}
$cipher = @mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, hexstr('25c506a9e4a0b3100d2d86b49b83cf9a'), $plain, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, hexstr('00000000000000000000000000000000'));

echo base64_encode($cipher);
echo "\n";
```

And

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -iv 0  -nosalt -in plain.txt  -K 25c506a9e4a0b3100d2d86b49b83cf9a -nopad
```

results the same:

```
EZjBup0sfRAkIZ2/IQ3bKHWXHG4qBVv4uyW0PnxJJWvWHanNgE1QyBHMpWoZqejR
```

Comment: Is there a way I can set what key to use with OpenSSL?

Comment: Edited the reply with sample PHP code that returns the same as an OpenSSL command. See how I used -K to ensure the sameness of key in OpenSSL and PHP. Also, use a more solid iv than 0, mcrypt has IV generating functions.

Comment: Thank you. What is hexstr() for?

Comment: Well, how do you plan to convert `25c506a9e4a0b3100d2d86b49b83cf9a` into the binary string PHP expects? I bet there's a `pack` command for that but I can never remember the pack magic. Edit: OK, editing the answer.

Comment: Don't you need salts and padding? Just using no salt or IV makes the code insecure. No padding means only use plain texts with with a size equal to N x block size.

Comment: Using a properly random IV is enough -- AES itself does not even have the concept of salt AFAIK. And yes, -nosalt is not necessary above. I have overshot there, sorry.

Comment: The salt is required to protect the key. If a new salt is created foreach ciphertext, then you don't require an IV because the key will always be different; the use of a random IV (not possible with OpenSSL as far as I know) doesn't mean you don't need the salt